# Does Google IoT Core have an OTA solution for the ESP32?

Tags: iot, esp32, ota, google-cloud-iot

We're scoping out a new industrial IoT product, and we are planning to use an ESP32 with Google's IoT Core.

Looking through the existing [Google IoT Core Docs](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/), AWS IoT Core has an entire section of their docs dedicated to OTAs ([AWS IoT Core OTA docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/freertos/latest/userguide/freertos-ota-dev.html)).

Am I right to assume that AWS IoT Core has much better support for OTAs than Google IoT Core?  Does anyone have examples or pointers to tutorial for how to use Google IoT Core to perform OTAs on an ESP32?

Other Considerations:

- I've seen that [MongooseOS](https://mongoose-os.com/) is a 3rd party option that's compatible with Google IoT Core, but we're really hoping for a Google-provided or something officially certified by Google. A good example of this is how AWS IoT Core officially supports FreeRTOS with OTAs on ESP32.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud IoT does not currently offer a first-party solution for OTA. That said, [Espressif offers OTA for ESP32](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/system/ota.html) in their platform that you could potentially trigger using configuration messages from Google Cloud IoT Core.

For getting the updated firmware to the device, we don't have a specific solution for ESP32 but there is an example of [how you could transmit a large file using Python with Google Cloud Storage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/iot/api-client/gcs_file_to_device) in the Python samples repo.

Comment: Is there a first-party solution to update the configuration of multiple devices at once? For OTA purposes.

Comment: You can take a look at mender.io. It is cross-platform and you can do both GCP, Azure and standalone devices as well.